# Dynamic borders in a Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 50 sheets in the workbook. The table header range is A:Z. The data range differs from sheet to sheet. I got VBA code which puts a border on the non-empty cells but some fields are blank in the data. Can somebody help with the script?

Below is the code that I tried modifying to apply to all sheets, in vain:

```
Sub testborder()

    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A14:K14" & endrow)

    'Clear existing
    rRng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

    'Apply new borders
    rRng.BorderAround xlContinuous
    rRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    rRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End Sub
```

Resolved by using the below code:

```
Sub AllWorksheetBorders()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Prevents screen refreshing
    Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCell As Range, r As Long, c As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        lngLstCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For Each rngCell In ws.Range("A21:A" & lngLstRow)
            If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
                r = rngCell.Row
                c = rngCell.Column

                With ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, c), ws.Cells(r, lngLstCol)).Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous    'Setting style of border line
                    .Weight = xlThin    'Setting weight of border line
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic    'Setting colour of border line
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    'Enables screen refreshing
End Sub
```

Comment: You said "all sheets" but your code has no attempt to loop all sheets. And some variables that are being used are not referenced on the code. More code is needed. Your "problem" is very simple with a simple For Loop to get all sheets, get the last used row and apply the border. I strongly recommend to spend some time learning the basics of VBA for Excel, which will teach you how to loop Sheets and the answer to your problem will be clear.

Comment: Read "tried modifying" , I hadn't included the code that I worked on. It's included now. I was able to resolve the issue. 

P.S - Please ask for missing info instead of down voting a question ;)

Comment: Nice edit and I am glad you found an answer. You seem to be mistaken. Read your first post before the edit and you will understand that without the missing data added later, it feels like you are requesting for someone to write the whole solution for you. Therefore the initial downvote.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I realize that my question didn't include my effort.

Comment: Posting your answer to the problem would also be of potential use to others with similar problems i.e. not as an edit to the question. In 2 days you can then accept it as answer.

Comment: I didn't know that I can my own question. I just added my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using the below code:

Sub AllWorksheetBorders()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Prevents screen refreshing
Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim rngCell As Range, r As Long, c As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lngLstCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For Each rngCell In ws.Range("A21:A" & lngLstRow)
        If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
            r = rngCell.Row
            c = rngCell.Column

            With ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, c), ws.Cells(r, lngLstCol)).Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous    'Setting style of border line
                .Weight = xlThin    'Setting weight of border line
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic    'Setting colour of border line
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True    'Enables screen refreshing
```

End Sub